# C program that displays the max of entered %2==0 numbers until you enter a number %2!=0 && %7==0

Tags: c, loops, numbers, nested

This program must take input from the user (a number) and repeat until a odd number dividable by 7 is entered. Then it must print the maximum of even numbers entered.

Tried two ways : nested and double while loop. The problem i'm having is that after i enter a number dividable by 7 but not odd (say 28) , if then i enter a odd number (say 3) the program prints max. It's supposed to let me enter numbers again until i enter one odd and dividable by 7 (let's say 21).

Nested code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x, max = 0, suma = 0, impar, par = 0;

    while (x % 7 != 0)
    { 
        while(x % 2 == 0 || x % 2 != 0)
        {
            printf("Introduceti un numar:\n");           //Enter a number
            scanf("%d", &x);
            if (x % 2 == 0)
                if (x > max)
                    max = x;
        }

        printf("Introduceti un numar:\n");            //Enter a number
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x % 2== 0)
            if (x > max)
                max = x;
        if (x % 2 != 0)
            break;
    }  
    printf("Maximul numerelor pare introduse este: %d",max);  
}
```

Why we're at it , i'm having trouble finding info about nested while loops in C. The inner loop is tested first by the compiler? Can someone explain with a simple example?

Comment: Modified it based on answer, now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, since you have a  `while` that depends on `x` *before*  you assign `x` a value. If you're going to input a value from the user, you can't test that value *before* reading it. Your `while` loops are not correctly expressing what you want to do.

It can be done using an infinite loop, and just `break`ing out when necessary.

And no, loops are (of course) not evaluated inside out. They are evaluated in the program order.

Comment: @Stack_token: You might also want to replace `scanf("%d", &x);` with `scanf(" %d", &x);` Note the space. This'll make scanf skip leading whitespace (including the EOL character) that might be in the input buffer